# Converting threaded to multi threaded code? ( task factory ?)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following threaded code ( i think ) form with a start and cancel button and a multilined text box, the commented sections (//) are from the working single threaded version and below i have tried to retrofit the multithreaded task.factory parts, however it seems to launch the powershell commands fine ( show in task manager ) but the program completes without waiting for the results from each "heavyOperation".

The idea is to start all the four HeavyOperation tasks at the same time (ish) and wait for each to return the results and append the results to the text box

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Progress<string> progressReporter = new Progress<string>();
    CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressReporter.ProgressChanged += progressManager_ProgressChanged;
    }

    async private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        btnCancel.Enabled = true;
        cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        //textBox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token));
        await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token));
        lblStatus.Text = "Completed.";           btnStart.Enabled = true;
        btnCancel.Enabled = false;
    }
    //private string PerfromTaskAction(CancellationToken ct)
    static void PerfromTaskAction(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        object[] arrObjects = new object[] { "SERVER1", "SERVER2", "SERVER3", "SERVER4" };

        foreach(object i in arrObjects)
        {
            //if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;
            //sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}\r\n", HeavyOperation(i.ToString()),i));
            //((IProgress<string>)progressReporter).Report(string.Format("Now Checking: {0}...", i));
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => HeavyOperation(i.ToString()));
        }
        //return sb.ToString();
    }
    void progressManager_ProgressChanged(object sender, string e)
    {          
        lblStatus.Invoke((Action)(() => lblStatus.Text = e));
    }
    //private string HeavyOperation(string i)
    public static void HeavyOperation(string i)
    {
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddCommand("invoke-command");
        ps.AddParameter("computername", i);
        ps.AddParameter("scriptblock", ScriptBlock.Create("get-vmreplication | select State"));
        Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
        //return result[0].Properties["State"].Value.ToString();
        Console.Write(result[0].Properties["State"].Value.ToString());
    }
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancelSource.Cancel();
    }

}
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: [`Task.Factory.StartNew(` is dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) you should use `Task.Run(` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to await for the `HeavyOperation`s to complete.

You can use `Task.WhenAll` for this purpose. Here is an `async` version of `PerformTaskAction`, using `Task.WhenAll`

I've taken into account **Scott Chamberlain**'s suggestions:

1. Changed the unsafe (in `async-await` context) `Task.Factory.StartNew()` to `Task.Run()`
2. Removed the unnecessary `await` in the invocation of `PerformTaskAction()`
3. Passed the missing `CancellationToken` in the outer `Task.Run()` call

   static async Task PerfromTaskAction(CancellationToken ct) {
            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   ```
        object[] arrObjects = new object[] { "SERVER1", "SERVER2", "SERVER3", "SERVER4" };
        IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(); // collect all tasks in single collection
        foreach( object i in arrObjects ) {
           //if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;
           //sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}\r\n", HeavyOperation(i.ToString()),i));
           //((IProgress<string>)progressReporter).Report(string.Format("Now Checking: {0}...", i));
           tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation(i.ToString())));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false); // wait asynchronously for all tasks to complete
     }
   ```

<s>Now that PerformTaskAction is async, you also need to await on it.</s>

Finally you invoke PerformTaskAction, making sure you also pass the CancellationToken.

```
await Task.Run( ()=> PerformTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token);
```

Comment: there is no need to await inside the `Task.Run` it has a overload that accepts `Func<Task>`, also you forgot to pass the token in to the method itself. `await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, dully noted. Will modify my answer to reflect your comments.  It's a bit frustrating to become aware that I still have a flaky "mental model" around async-await. In my mind if it is async, you await... anyways, thanks for the observations.